# adding css stylesheet to ejs file makes page load indefinitely

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making an express app, and I have two /get routes: one executes a function that does res.render("file.ejs") that has a css stylesheet in it and everything works, and the other executes an async function that does things before rendering (the fact one is async is the only difference I can spot; I even made them render the same file and the result was the same: the async one didn't load). There is no error in the console on the website or server side, the page just keeps loading (it's not just the css not loading, the contents of the page are also missing)
I know all files are referenced correctly because when I remove the stylesheet from the ejs file the page loads its contents.
Is there anything to that async being there or should I look for the error somewhere else?

I am pretty new to this, but Thanks in advance.

Comment: okay I just did await res.render, and now the page loads the contents, but the css is not applied, the stylesheet gets loaded from http://localhost/styles.css rather than the file directory.

Comment: Probably your server doesn't have an appropriate route to serve the css file.  Normally, you would put static resources in a `public` directory and then create a route using `express.static()` that will serve all your public, static resources.  You will have to make sure you use the proper URLs in your page to load the static resources properly.  For further help, show us both your Express code and the HTML of the page in question and describe where in your server file system the css file is located.

Comment: In the future, questions here about code should always include the relevant code.  That allows people to write specific and accurate answers that apply precisely to your specific code which gets you better answers and makes the answers more meaningful for everyone else.

Comment: okay, next time I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: Well, if you edit your current question to include that info, we can write a specific answer for this question.

Comment: Agree with @jfriend00

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.